# Android TabLayout Fragment communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-design-library

From com.android.support:design:22.2.0 I've implemented a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

I have a vanilla fragments, 3 of them in the TabLayout.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment impliments SyncInfo.SyncInfo {
    ....
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void synced() {
        //refresh some info in the fragment!
    }
}
```

Additionally I've implemented a FragmentPagerAdapter to manage the tabLayout.

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

     public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                 return new MyFragment();
            case 1:
                 return new MyFragment2();
            default:
                 return new MyFragment3();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Now in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter( new   FragmentPagerAdapterApp(getSupportFragmentManager(), this) );


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ....
     }
```

Next, I have some Asynctasks defined, and in the onPostExecute of the Asynctask I'd like to implement a way to communicate back to each fragment as needed.

```
public class SyncInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   private final SyncResponse syncResponse;

   public SyncInfo(Context context...) {
       ....
        syncResponse = (SyncResponse) context;
    }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      ...
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        syncResponse.synced();
    }

    public interface SyncResponse{
        void synced();
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing this via an interface defined in the AsyncTask and have the methods implemented in the fragment, but this did not work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to pass information/trigger methods in the fragments that are created with the FragmentPageAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem before and I end up using event bus solutions such as [Otto](http://github.com/square/otto) by Square. They have an sampe app in the repository.

Alternatively, you can use Android built-in [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to communitate between the fragments.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense to implement something a little bit more of a robust solution in this case. I'll check out Otto, it seems like it would be the best fit just reading the docs quickly (in my case).